# How can I return the element number of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, element

I have written the code below and now I need to edit it so that it displays the checkout numbers that have taken more than 3000. i.e.it must display:

The following checkouts have taken more than 3000.00 pounds:
                Checkout Number "element number"
                Checkout Number "element number" etc

I've been trying a few different approaches but haven't been successful yet. Thanks for your help !

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Checkouts
{
   static final int NUMBER_OF_CHECKOUTS = 6, MAX_TAKING = 1000000;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      double[] checkoutList = new double[NUMBER_OF_CHECKOUTS];

  System.out.println();
  for (int index = 0; index < checkoutList.length; index++)
  {
     System.out.print("\tEnter takings for checkout number ");
     System.out.print((index + 1) + ": ");
     checkoutList[index] = scan.nextDouble();
     while (checkoutList[index] < 0 || checkoutList[index] > MAX_TAKING)
     {
        System.out.print("\tImpossible! - enter takings for checkout number ");
        System.out.print((index + 1) + " again: ");
        checkoutList[index] = scan.nextDouble();
     } 
  }
  System.out.println();
  double totalTakings = 0;
  for (int index = 0; index < checkoutList.length; index++)
  {
     totalTakings += checkoutList[index];
  }

  System.out.println("The total takings for the supermarket is " + totalTakings );
```

}
}

Comment: Can you explain what your code does? What approached did you take?

Comment: You already know how to write a for loop, and I guess you also know about the `if` statement. So you should be able to combine both to implement what you want. Loop over the checkouts, and *if* one is above 3000, then print its index.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a for loop that goes through each index we can just do the check in there:

```
  System.out.println("The following checkouts have taken more than 3000.00 pounds:");
  for (int index = 0; index < checkoutList.length; index++)
  {
     totalTakings += checkoutList[index];

     if(checkoutList[index] > 3000.00){
         //now we can be sure the current index is the location of
         //a checkout that was > 3000.00 pounds
         System.out.println("Checkout Number: " + index);
     }
  }
```